# Problem with Stash nested lists

Tags: stash, nested-list

I'm working on an XML template for a site and need to output a series of listings where URLs look like:

/store/#type#/#brand#/#collection#/

My entries are set up so that there's an entry for each brand with a matrix row for each collection (type is a category of the entry).

So I need to loop through the entries in the channel and then loop through the matrix rows for each entry and output a `<url>` pair for all of them.

With the code below I get output if I don't have the `exp:stash:get_list:nested` tag (but with incorrect URLs), but with it, I get nothing.

```
{exp:stash:set_list
    name="collections"
    parse_depth="2"
    parse_tags="yes"
}
    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="brands"
        disable="member_data|pagination|trackbacks"
        dynamic="no"
    }
        {stash:collection_url_title}{url_title}{/stash:collection_url_title}

        {stash:collection_entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:collection_entry_id}

        {stash:collection_type}{categories}{category_url_title}{/categories}{/stash:collection_type}

        {exp:stash:set_list:nested name="collection_{collection_entry_id}" parse_tags="yes"}
            {cat_images}
                {stash:collection_cat}{exp:cat2:url_title category_id='{cat}'}{/stash:collection_cat}
            {/cat_images}
        {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}

    {/exp:channel:entries}

{/exp:stash:set_list}

{exp:stash:get_list name="collections"}

    {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="collection_{collection_entry_id}"}
        <url>
            <loc>http://www.domain.com.au/store/{collection_type}/{collection_url_title}/{collection_cat}/</loc>
        </url>
    {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}

{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried append_list? e.g. `{exp:stash:append_list:nested name="collection_{collection_entry_id}" parse_tags="yes"}`

Comment: Oh shouldn't `{collection_entry_id}` in `{exp:stash:set_list:nested name="collection_{collection_entry_id}" parse_tags="yes"}` actually be just `{entry_id}` i.e `collection_{entry_id}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the context parameter and a unique identifier in your nested list. Generally using entry_id is the easiest way to create a relationship between your two lists.

1. Stash `{entry_id}` in your outer list (used for retrieval wit get_list)
2. Set the `context` parameter in your nested list and feed it `{entry_id}` from your outer list
3. when getting your nested list, use the `context` parameter again and feed it the stashed `{stash_entry_id}` from step one.

Here is a [detailed explanation and example on the Stash wiki](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/Lists#three-and-more-dimensional-lists).

Comment: Yep, that's done it. I was following the example at https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp%3Astash%3Aset_list%7D#nesting Seems the one you've linked to is more recent.